# TableView gets inconsistent behaviour when scrolling down/up

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a ViewController that has a TableView. The tableView cell has a StackView with two images in it and outside it a label.

In the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` I get the cell and my data is inside a arrayList. And this is what I do:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier = "NamesTableViewCell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! NamesTableViewCell

    let _name = _Names[indexPath.row]

    if indexPath.row % 2 != 0 {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexString: "ededed")
    }

    cell.labelName.text = _name.name

    if _name.gender! == "M" {
        cell.pinkCircleImageView.hidden = true
    } else if _name.gender! == "F" {
        cell.blueCircleImageView.hidden = true
    }

    return cell
}
```

So as you can see I hide the images depending on the gender of the name and also change the background of every other cell.

Now, the behavior I am seeing is:

https://gyazo.com/1b2d39696892b7fb2f15b71696d9a925

The gender is available for every object, I've checked.

What do you guys think? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cell.pinkCircleImageView.hidden = false
cell.blueCircleImageView.hidden = false

if _name.gender! == "M" {
    cell.pinkCircleImageView.hidden = true
    cell.bringSubviewToFront(blueCircleImageView)
} else if _name.gender! == "F" {
    cell.blueCircleImageView.hidden = true
    cell.bringSubviewToFront(pinkCircleImageView)
}

if indexPath.row % 2 == 0
{
    cell.backgroundColor=UIColor.whiteColor()
}
else
{
    cell.backgroundColor=UIColor(red: 248/255, green: 248/255, blue: 248/255, alpha: 1.0)
}
```

Comment: Hi Jayesh. Thanks so much, it totally works! I must say I don't understand why it does work, though. What does bringSubviewToFront() means?

Also, there is one last problem. The cell background color is getting lost. It should be white and then gray. But when I scroll down, everything turns just gray. Any idea why? THanks again

Comment: bringSubviewToFront() means Moves the specified subview so that it appears on top of its siblings.

Comment: The cell background color should be white and then gray ...try edit answer

Comment: And that's it! It's all working now. The problem was that I was not setting the cell back to white color , so upon scrolling it kept the gray one.
Thanks so man!